# Motivation of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, motivation

Let $V$ and $W$ be linear spaces, $D$ be a subspace of $V$, and $f:D\to W$ be a linear map.

Why do functional analysts call $f$ an operator on $V$ instead of a linear map on $D$?

Comment: Perhaps an operator $F$ is defined on all of $V$, and $f$ is its restriction to the subspace $D$, i.e. $f = F|_D$. By abuse, they're using the same name. It's not great, but context should make it clear.

Comment: For unbounded operators this is sometimes due to the fact that it is hard to write down $D$ (the domain of definition) and also kind of not that relevant (mostly we are taking it in such a way that the operator is self-adjoint and that it contains bump functions). Furthermore, typically $V$ is a space where the norm is clear from context (e.g. $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$).